# How to detect in javascript if a field is on focus and clear the error besides it?

Tags: javascript

I have the function

```
function validateEmailp() {
var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
var first = two.split("@")[1];
var badEmails = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"]
if (badEmails.indexOf(first) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("email").value = ""; 
    document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = 'We do not accept free e-mails' 
    return false;
    }   
 return true;
}
```

HTML is

```
<input id="email" onblur="validateEmailp()"><div id="emailerrorz"></div>
```

After the user types in the input field a free e-mail he will get that error (we do not..)
But after he rectify the email to a non-free e-mail the error should clear up. How do i do that with javascript?

Comment: tried `document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText='';` ...??

Comment: @davidkonrad And how exactly would i do that because i think that i need to verify smth, like if the field is on focus or don't exactly.

Comment: As an aside, why on earth don't you accept "free e-mails"? And do you really think you can hard-code a list of all possible free e-mail account providers? Your code wouldn't block my free e-mail account, and even though you've tried to block yahoo.com you haven't blocked the non-US Yahoo accounts like yahoo.com.au, etc...

Comment: @nnnnnn I have a list of 800 free email providers :) Including all yahoo domains.

Comment: And you still won't have a complete list; regardless, the question of 'why' remains interesting, and unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validateEmailp() {
    var two = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var first = two.split("@")[1];
    var badEmails = ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com"]
    if (badEmails.indexOf(first) > -1) {
        document.getElementById("email").value = ""; 
        document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = 'We do not accept free e-mails' 
        return false;
    } 
    document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = '' 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an `else` case:

```
if (badEmails.indexOf(first) != -1) {
    document.getElementById("email").value = ""; 
    document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = 'We do not accept free e-mails' 
    return false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('emailerrorz').innerText = ""; // clear error
}
```